# PHP / JSON: Sort two different timestamp formats in one array

Tags: php, json, facebook, datetime, sorting

I have a merged array from the JSON output of a Facebook and Twitter stream and I want to sort those two into one but they offer two different timestamps:

Facebook: `[created_time] => 1299839651`
Twitter: `[created_at] => Mon Mar 07 16:33:49 +0000 2011`

Currently the output contains the full JSON content from both platforms beginning with `Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] =>` (Facebook) and ending with `[id_str] => 12345678964508161 ) )` (Twitter).
In the middle part it looks like this: `&limit=25&until=0 ) [0] => Array ( [text] =>` (Facebook -> Twitter).
I am not sure how to handle this. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtotime()` to convert the Twitter timestamp into one that looks more like the Facebook timestamp.

Then you simply order them based on the numerical timestamp

Answer (score 0):

This should work, assuming I understood your problem correctly.

```
<?php

// assume $array is your array of associative arrays with created_time 
// being facebook timestamps, created_at being twitter


// takes as arguments two associative arrays with
// created_time keys to compare
function sort_by_created_time($arr1, $arr2)
{
    if ($arr1['created_time'] == $arr2['created_time'])
    {
        return 0;
    }
    elseif ($arr1['created_time'] > $arr2['created_time'])
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

// go through each array, generate timestamps if needed
foreach ($array as &$row)
{
    if (!isset($row['created_time']))
    {
        // convert date formats to timestamps if we need to
        $row['created_time'] = strtotime($row['created_at']);
    }
}
unset($row);

usort($array, "sort_by_created_time");
```